# PHP Remove Punctuation (No Dashes)

Tags: php, replace, character

I found the below script here on stackoverflow and it replaces special characters with dashes for the purpose of clean url building. But, it doesnt do it well as it replaces punctuation with dashes as seen in the "bad" example below. So, instead I would like specifically punctuation to NOT be replaced with anything but to just be removed... no white space, no dash. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

example:

```
today's weather is hot!
```

good:

```
todays-weather-is-hot
```

bad:

```
today-s-weather-is-hot-
```

This script does the bad example... how to make it do the good?:

```
function slugUrl($string) {
    $string = strtolower($string);
    $string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/i','-',$string);
    $string = preg_replace("/(-){2,}/",'$1',$string);
    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this? (I just removed the punctuation first)

```
function slugUrl($string){
    $string = strtolower($string);
    $string = preg_replace('/[!?\']/','',$string);
    $string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/i','-',$string);
    $string = preg_replace("/(-){2,}/",'$1',$string);
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: I'd also `trim()` the white spaces first.

Comment: Bah... Why not. Good idea. There's a lot to improve here.

Comment: Yeah it still gives the "bad" result. How to use trim() here?

Comment: What kind of bad result does it give?

Comment: See edited post. It was just a typo on the first `preg_replace`, we need to replace by empty string, not space. My bad. Tired. Just tested and it works now.

Comment: `today's weather is hot ` becomes `todays-weather-is-hot-` because of trailing space or some non alpha numeric, non `!?'` character. One extra line `$string = trim($string, '-');` should fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by first removing all those characters you are not interested in and then replacing only spaces with the dash.

Additionally [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) allows to run multiple replace operations at once when using arrays ([Demo](http://eval.in/5618)):

```
$subject = 'today\'s weather is hot!';

$buffer = trim(strtolower($subject));
$result = preg_replace(['/[^a-z0-9 ]/', '/\s+/'], ['', '-'], $buffer);
```

Result (without the quotes):

```
"todays-weather-is-hot"
```

In form of a function:

```
function slugUrl($string){
    return preg_replace(
        array('/[^a-z0-9 ]/', '/\s+/'), 
        array(''            , '-'    ), 
        trim(strtolower($string))
     );
}
```

Comment: Oh i like this. Im gonna try this too.

Comment: Yes, if you don't have the current stable PHP 5.4 version, you need to use `array(...)` instead of `[...]`, it's the more modern notation in PHP I use here for brevity.